# ZABBIX「Query failed: ERROR: null value in column "posts" violates not-null constraint」

Tags: postgresql, zabbix

An error has occurred and items cannot be added.

```
pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: null value in column "posts" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL: Failing row contains (57698, 7, , , 10180, Log(test), logrt[/var/log/test.log], 30, 90d, 0, 0, 2, , , , 0, , , , , 0, , null, null, , , 0, , , , , 0, 0, null, , , 0, 30d, 0, 0, 0, , 0, , null, 3s, , , null, 200, 1, 0, , , 0, 0, 0, , , , 0, 0, 0).

[items.php:749 → CFrontendApiWrapper->create() → CApiWrapper->__call() → CFrontendApiWrapper->callMethod() → CApiWrapper->callMethod() → CFrontendApiWrapper->callClientMethod() → CLocalApiClient->callMethod() → call_user_func_array() → CItem->create() → CItem->createReal() → DB::insert() → DBexecute() → pg_query() in include/db.inc.php:487]

Error in query [INSERT INTO items (hostid,name,type,key_,snmp_oid,snmp_community,snmpv3_contextname,snmpv3_securityname,snmpv3_securitylevel,snmpv3_authprotocol,snmpv3_authpassphrase,snmpv3_privprotocol,snmpv3_privpassphrase,port,authtype,username,password,publickey,privatekey,params,ipmi_sensor,value_type,units,delay,history,trends,valuemapid,logtimefmt,trapper_hosts,inventory_link,description,status,master_itemid,flags,query_fields,headers,itemid) VALUES ('10180','Log(test)','7','logrt[/var/log/test.log]','','','','','0','0','','0','','','0','','','','','','','2','','30','90d','0',NULL,'','','0','','0',NULL,'0','','','57698')] [ERROR: null value in column "posts" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL: Failing row contains (57698, 7, , , 10180, Log(test), logrt[/var/log/test.log], 30, 90d, 0, 0, 2, , , , 0, , , , , 0, , null, null, , , 0, , , , , 0, 0, null, , , 0, 30d, 0, 0, 0, , 0, , null, 3s, , , null, 200, 1, 0, , , 0, 0, 0, , , , 0, 0, 0).]
```

Please give me advice on measures

*　postgresSQL 11.5
* Zabbix-server 4.2